# Dynamic Dropdown, MS Excel, Use on Multiple Rows (MS365)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

### Goal

Using Excel table ("Claims") to track claim statuses, have dropdown values in certain columns (in Columns C, D, F, G) in which the dropdown values for Columns D, F and G are Dynamically generated based on values from other columns on the same row.

### Situtation

While I have gotten this to work on a single row (Row 4, which is my initial data entry row), I cannot figure out how to get this to work for subsequent rows.

### Worksheets

***Claims*** - Data Entry

***InsurancePlanList*** - Insurance Plan and Claims Type Information
|A|B|C|
|-|-|-|
|PlanName|PolicyNumber|Type|

***ProviderListing*** - List of Facilities and Providers
|A|B|C|
|-|-|-|
|Type|Facility|Provider|

***UniqueLists*** - Sheet to hold Dynamic Lists
|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|
|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|
|Plan Type||Insurance Plans||Facility List||Provider List|

Plan Type `=SORT(IF(UNIQUE(InsurancePlanList!$C$2:$C$300,FALSE,FALSE)=0,"",UNIQUE(InsurancePlanList!$C$2:$C$300,FALSE,FALSE)))`

Insurance Plans `=SORT(UNIQUE(IF(FILTER(Insurance_Plans[PlanName],Insurance_Plans[Type]=Claims!C4,"")=0,"",FILTER(Insurance_Plans[PlanName],Insurance_Plans[Type]=Claims!C4,"")),FALSE,FALSE))`

Facility List
`=SORT(UNIQUE(IF(FILTER(Provider_and_Facility[Facility],Provider_and_Facility[Type]=Claims!C4,"")=0,"",FILTER(Provider_and_Facility[Facility],Provider_and_Facility[Type]=Claims!C4,"")),FALSE,FALSE))`

Provider List
`=SORT(UNIQUE(IF(FILTER(Provider_and_Facility[Provider],(Provider_and_Facility[Type]=Claims!C4)*(Provider_and_Facility[Facility]=Claims!F4),"")=0,"",FILTER(Provider_and_Facility[Provider],(Provider_and_Facility[Type]=Claims!C4)*(Provider_and_Facility[Facility]=Claims!F4),"")),FALSE,FALSE))`

[image: Unique Lists Screen Shot]

### Claim Worksheet Columns

Column C: Claim Type is list of static values which are populated from UniqueLists!$A$2#

Column D: Insurance Plan - Dynamic List where values are based off of Column C's selection and populated from UniqueLists!$C$2#

Column F: Facility - Dynamic List where values are based off of Column C's selection and populated from UniqueLists!$E$2#

Column G: Provider - Dynamic List where values are based off of Column C and Column F selection and populated from UniqueLists!$G$2#
[image: Claims Worksheet Screenshot]

### Notes

While this works on Row 4 of Claims, I cannot figure out how to get this to apply for Columns D, F and G on the other rows. Since Column C's List is non-dynamic, I have been able to get that to work. Guidance on if and how to get this to work would be appreciated.

### Previous Posting Disclosure

I previously asked a version of this question on the MrExcel Message Board last week using the title "Using Dynamic Validation Lists for every row in table"

Comment: Am I missing something in this ask? I think VBA is needed to build a dynamic list based on the cursor's cell location AND based on what values were entered (in any) into the other cells. Good luck.

Comment: @gns100 If I am using it only on one row, the dropdowns work as expected It is only when I want to move it to use it on multiple rows.